# Skipping Commented Lines with QStrings

Tags: string, qt, parsing, stream, comments

I would like to skip over commented lines in the text file that I am parsing using QStrings.

How would one go about skipping over any line that starts with the character '#' for example?

This is what I have currently:

```
     QTextStream in(&inputFile);
     QList< QStringList > lists;
     QString inputLines;

     do {
          inputLines = in.readLine();
          lists << inputLines.split("\t");

        } while (!inputLines.isNull());
          .
          .
          .
```

Comment: Which QString functions have you tried to use to find out how the string `startsWith`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`QString::startsWith(QString)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#startsWith) to filter the lines before processing them like in the following example:

```
QStringList lines = ...;
foreach(QString line, lines)
{
    line = line.trimmed(); // if you want to ignore whitespaces at both ends
    if(!line.startsWith("#"))
        processLine(line);
}
```

Comment: I didn't use your example exactly as is, but the startsWith function which you and Roku suggested was what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: If it's only one character, you could also write `line.length() && line.at(0) == '#'` which may be slightly faster (note the length > 0 check before accessing character at index 0). But in most cases it doesn't make a difference.